# Android issue while exit my application

Tags: android, exit, livecycle

Sorry if it is already answered, I searched and not found (may be my key words are wrong) because I found explanation how force exit application, or exit all activity, ... But it is not my issue. My application exit well.

I have a strange issue while I exit my application.
Step to reproduce my issue (And it is at each time I do the following steps) :

1. I launch an application X, by example a game, Android parameters, the "hello world" default Application, ...
2. I press HOME key
3. Now I launch (from list of application) my application
4. I press back to exit my application
5. My application exit
6. The application launched in (1) automatically launched instead of
   return to home

For information : I exit my application on capture back key, ask user if really want exit, if he says yes I call `finish()`

--EDIT 1 start--
I can share some code the finish method (Inside the Activity) :

```
private void reallyExitTheApplication()
{
   if(this.serviceLink!=null)
   {
      this.unbind(this.serviceConnection);
      this.serviceLink = null;
   }

   this.finish();
}
```

And the code that call it

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        // ...
        case R.id.buttonValidateExit :
            this.reallyExitTheApplication();
            break;
       // ...
    }
}
```

--EDIT 1 end--

-- EDIT 2 start --

I add also the manifest part for my Activity :

```
<activity
    android:name="jhelp.tests.browser.BrowserManagerActivity"
android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:label="@string/browserName"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:taskAffinity="jhelp.tests.browser">
    <intent-filter>
        <action 
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category
           android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.mozilla.gecko.LOAD"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action 
            android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action 
            android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

-- EDIT 2 end --

Any idea why Android decide to launch the application (1) instead of return to home ?

I have built lot of application before, its first time I see this.

Thanks for any help

JHelp

Comment: I can share you the exit function :

Comment: yes, add it to your question

Answer (score 0):

The first Apllication which you opened had SplashScreen on the screen.

you pressed home button and started your app in the mean time first application's mainActivity added to back of application two so(its like two activity one on another) so when you pressed back application first main activity you saw.

Comment: No the first application not have a splash screen (and its not mine), it could also be the Android parameters. I mean the issue happen regardless what is the first application. And I didn't notice this issue on any other application I previously developed or used